# Why does my terminal start up with "(eval):export:1: not valid in this context"?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, postgresql, vmware-fusion

When I open my terminal, it shows up with the error

```
(eval):export:1: not valid in this context: Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
```

I can't figure out what is causing this error, mainly because I don't have Postgres installed. It seems like the error might be coming from VMware Fusion, which I do have.

I'm using macOS 10.14.5, zsh 5.3, I have VMware Fusion 11.1.0 installed. I used to have Postgres installed (for working with Heroku), but I realized I didn't need it for my project, so I deleted it.

Comment: Try digging down into the Fusion app, right click, Show Contents. The path `Public:/Applications` is very odd, colons are not allowed in Mac filenames

Comment: I made an asciinema [here] (https://asciinema.org/a/WyR23EEGrH4FYYk5u5KxAG1wl). There isn't much in the app. I'm not sure what script is making that error. It seems like it happens during setup of the shell, because it only appears when I open a new shell instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was that my path included Postgress and VMWare despite uninstalling them. They were not added in .zshrc, but actually in /etc/paths.d (which is a directory). Inside this directory, there were 3 files, two of them named `com.vmware.fusion.public` and `postgresapp`.
I simply deleted these files from /etc/paths.d, and now my zsh starts up with no error!

Thanks @MatrixManAtYrService for starting me down the path to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

I get something similar:

```
(eval):export:1: not valid in this context: -A
```

In my case, it started when the `gcloud` installer modified my .zshrc to add this line:

```
if [ -f '/Users/matt/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc' ]; then . '/Users/matt/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc'; fi
```

I get the error whenever I try to tab-complete gcloud commands.

Commenting out that line makes the error go away.  Did a VMWare or Postgres installer modify your .zshrc?  You might need to remove whatever modifications it made.

Answer (score 1):

VMWare Fusion adds itself to the path by adding a file `/etc/paths.d/com.vmware.fusion.public`. The file contains an unescaped space which is causing the error.

Run `sudo su root` to switch the the root user (owner of the /etc/paths.d directory) then run `sudo echo /Applications/VMware\\\ Fusion.app/Contents/Public > /etc/paths.d/com.vmware.fusion.public` to replace the path with one escaping the space character then `exit` to return to your user.